# Using Bash variable in SSH config

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have the hostname of a server set in my `.bash_profile` on shell initialization. How can I use that variable as part of my ssh `config` file like so:

`.bash_profile`

```
...

MY_SERVER='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

...
```

`~/.ssh/config`

```
Host my-host
    User uname
    HostName <MY_SERVER var here>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-pem.pem
```

I have tried both

```
HostName $MY_SERVER
```

and

```
HostName ${MY_SERVER}
```

but both result in the error: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname $MY_SERVER: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Is there a way to do this without running a script on shell initialization to inject the hostname into the config file?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to have `ssh` use the environment as part of the configuration. You have to hard-code the host name.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Add a function with name ssh in your ~/.bash_profile to create a new config file (e.g. ~/.ssh/myconfig) with content of variable $MY_SERVER and use this file with ssh's option -F in this function.

Comment: This can be construed as a shell programming question. It seems on-topic to me as a Bash scripting concern, and I don't believe it should be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can't do this directly, because the SSH configuration file isn't parsed by Bash. However, you could certainly run a script or function at from your shell's interactive login resource file (e.g. *~/.bashrc*) that uses *m4* or *sed* to create a *~/.ssh/config* file.

---

**Note: Preserve your sanity. If you modify *~/.ssh/config* dynamically, it's best to create a copy from *~/.ssh/config.orig* or similar, rather than modifying the configuration file in-place.**

---

It is much easier (and safer) to create an alias or function to do this for you at run-time, rather than trying to modify a configuration file dynamically. It should also be much easier to list and debug aliases, but your mileage may vary. Examples of aliasing follow in the sections below.

### Simple Aliases, One Per Host

The easiest thing to do is create simple aliases for each unique hostname. For example:

```
# ~/.bashrc
alias foo='ssh foo.example.com'
alias bar='ssh bar.example.com'
```

You can add customized options to each alias using the ssh `-o` flag too, if you like. Usage and available flag options are listed in the [ssh(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/slogin.1?query=ssh&sec=1) man page.

### Aliases with Paramater Expansion

A more complex solution takes advantage of Bash's `:+` [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). This method creates a single alias that overrides the HostName option if the *MY_SERVER* variable has been set. For example:

```
alias ssh='ssh ${MY_SERVER:+-o HostName="$MY_SERVER"}'
```

will override the SSH HostName option only when *MY_SERVER* is set. For example, given a Host of `foo` and a HostName of `foo.example.com`:

```
$ MY_SERVER=foo.example.com
$ ssh foo
```

will expand to:

> ssh -o Hostname=foo.example.com foo

Just use `\ssh` or `command ssh` to run SSH directly without alias expansion when necessary.

Comment: Awesome! Instead of an alias using a variable, I added a small shell function called shh (secure SHell to Host) to ~/.bashrc that runs ssh -o Hostname=$2 $1 . That way, I just $ shh {profileName} {hostName} . Works great for EC2 where hosts come and go, serving differing roles but with similar IPs, etc.